# How to setup custom currency symbol for Jaspersoft report for docker application

Tags: java, docker-compose, jasper-reports, currency-formatting

Currently using the below code

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="¤ #,##0.00" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="45" height="12" />
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}]]></textFieldExpression> 
</textField>
```

the currency symbol is appearing as it is like '¤'.

I want to know what property to setup in yml file for this to take up correct currency symbol pass through Java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed the locale while creating jasperreport which solved my problem.